# How to use a POS Tagger NLTK for an Imported CSV File in Python 3

Tags: python, csv

I have a question -- Right now I have code that imports a CSV file where the first column is full of words in the following format:

```
This
Is
The
Format
```

Once this CSV file is uploaded and read by Python, I want to be able to tag these words using an NLTK POS Tagger.  Right now, my code goes like this

```
Import CSV
with open(r'C:\Users\jkk\Desktop\python.csv', 'r') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
J = []
for row in reader:
   J.extend(row)
import nltk
nltk.pos_tag(J)
print(J)
```

However, when I print it, I only get:

> ['This ', 'Is ', 'The', 'Format']

without the POS Tag!

I'm not sure why this isn't working as I am very new to Python 3.  Any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pos_tag` *creates and returns a new list*; it doesn't modify its argument. Assign the new list back to the same name:

```
J = nltk.pos_tag(J)
```

Comment: Wonderful, that was exactly what I needed!  Thank you very much!  Just another quick question if you have the time -- in regards to that code I posted above, the POS tagger is reading all capital letter as NNP even when they are not.  Is there a quick was to make all the words lowercase?  Thanks!